# alternative to recursive sql / dedupe columns

Tags: sql, pandas

Hi I have a `data set` with one to many relations. I want to reduce it to 1-1 by `concatenating` the distinct values for each column

Here is an example:

I have a data set called `Customer` and `Product Affiliation (PA)`. One `customer` can have `multiple PA` for different times.

Here is the input:

```
╔════════╦═══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ Cust   ║PA1    ║ PA2  ║ PA3  ║
╠════════╬═══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ A      ║ H     ║ M    ║ L    ║
║ A      ║ H     ║ L    ║ M    ║
║ A      ║ H     ║ M    ║ H    ║
╚════════╩═══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Desired output:

```
╔════════╦══════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║  Cust  ║  PA1 ║   PA2    ║  PA3  ║
╠════════╬══════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║  A     ║  H   ║   M&L    ║ L&M&H ║
╚════════╩══════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

i have multiple PA columns. I want to know if there is a generic python panda code I can apply
Thank you
MInc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly expanded version of the sample data to make it more clear how the code operates on groups rather than the whole dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Cust':list('AAABBB'),'PA1':list('HHHMMH'),
                    'PA2': list('MLMMMM'),'PA3':[1,2,3,3,3,1] })

  Cust PA1 PA2 PA3
0    A   H   M   1
1    A   H   L   2
2    A   H   M   3
3    B   M   M   3
4    B   M   M   3
5    B   H   M   1
```

The first step is just to create a new dataframe with one row per customer.  This is just a quick and dirty way to do it that is fine for the example at hand but you might want to do it differently depending on what you want to do with any other columns.

```
df2 = df.groupby('Cust').sum()

      PA1  PA2  PA3
Cust               
A     HHH  MLM  123
B     MMH  MMM  331
```

With that as a template for the desired output, we can just loop over the relevant columns of the original dataframe and use `groupby/apply` with `join/unique` to replace the values in the existing columns:

```
for col in ['PA1','PA2','PA3']:
    df2[col] = df.groupby('Cust')[col].apply( lambda x: 
                                              '&'.join( x.astype(str).unique() ))

      PA1  PA2    PA3
Cust                 
A       H  M&L  1&2&3
B     M&H    M    3&1
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the solution. I tried to apply this on my data set. However it gives an error "TypeError:sequence item 0: expected string , int found".Upon close inspection..my data set has dates and integers ..so i converted the data frame to strings using applymap(str)..that is still not helping..how can i concatenate the values ?

Comment: Here is an example                                                                          date(2015-07-11,2015-07-11,2015-07-11) | cust(A, A, A)  | Rating (H, M, L) |Count (0,0,0) |note_count(1,2,3).                                                               The data types include datetime64[ns], object, float64.Error message is TypeError:sequence item 0: expected string, bumpy.int64 found

Comment: @pmv  I edited the code by adding `astype(str)` to the last line of code.  I think that should solve it.

Comment: Hi The issue is with the date time stamp. when i use the as type ..the error i get is TypeError:cannot as type a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [|S0]

Comment: @pmv  I think this may be an issue that was fixed in version 0.16.1.  If you are using 0.16.0 or earlier, can you try upgrading and see if that fixes it?  I am using 0.16.2 and don't have the same problem.

Comment: Hi John..Thanks ..I am using .14..However I was able to accomplish what needed by converting the entire data frame to string and then applying date formats to the final dataset